# Remove a segment but keeping the value

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to remove a segment of an url but keep the value of it passing in the url trew the routes.
I have an url like:

`www.aaa.com/something/something1/tag/something3`

I need to remove the "tag/" but when I remove it the page are not anymore accessible.

`str_ireplace('TAG/','', $click);`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. :(

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?  You want to save the URL to two variables?  One without the "tag/", and one that is only the "tag/"?

Comment: It seems you're using some framework. If that's the case, wich one?

Comment: When I click on the first link with a "tag/", it shows a page with the value of something3. But If I remove the "tag/", the routes.php can't find anymore the page, so it doesn't load the value something3

Comment: the developper told me to write a specific condition that look for something3 as the first segment and replace the "tag/".
First, I'm asking me if I can override that with a str_ireplace  and a dynamic value to make believe to routes.php that the "tag/" is still here.

Comment: @sergio, that's Joomla and the routes comes from Jreviews.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure of what you mean, but if it is that you want to save `tag/` to one variable and the rest of the url to another, here is what you could do.  Use `explode` and `implode` on the forward slashes, save the `tag/` key to a variable and `unset` it from the array:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.aaa.com/something/something1/tag/something3";
$url = explode('/',$url);
$segment = $url[5] . '/';
unset($url[5]);
$url = implode('/',$url);
echo "segment: ".$segment."<br>";
echo "url: ".$url;
?>
```

Comment: I believe the double forward slashes after http: would create an empty key, $url[1], making tag $url[5]

Comment: Ok, I try and will come back.